# Are high n_estimators good?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model, regression

I created a model with CatBoostRegressor. My dataset is 74274 rows × 24 columns.I am using encoding and min-max scaler.

The more I raise the n_estimators value in my model, the better the model score. What is the end of this? How do I decide where to stop? That way I guess it goes forever. Is being high good or bad? Where should the stopping point be?

model = CatBoostRegressor(n_estimators=3000,verbose=False)

model = CatBoostRegressor(n_estimators=10000,verbose=False)

model = CatBoostRegressor(n_estimators=20000,verbose=False)

.

.

.

Comment: It depends on your application. Increasing n_estimators will increase the running time of your model. You may need to calculate the validation score while increasing n_estimators and stop increasing n_estimators when the relative improvements on the validation set will start to diminish.

Comment: Thanks, can we always say higher model.score is better? Is it okay to focus on that?

Comment: Nope, increasing the number of trees may lead to overfitting. Some example: https://www.thekerneltrip.com/statistics/does-gradient-boosting-overfit/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which set are you checking the score upon?

If that's a train set, the score will likely keep increasing because of overfitting.

For a validation set, the score should stop increasing at a certain point once the order of model complexity becomes comparable to the sample size.

Sklearn/skopt cross validation routines such as `GridSearchCV()` should aid you in automating the best hyperparameters' selection.